# How can I add PHP as content with HTML editor?

Tags: php

Using Drupal 7 with CIVI crm 5.x[image]

I'm doing some testing with this:

Hello World'; ?>

Paste it in source code, but then it strips it out like this:

```
  <!--?php echo '<p-->
  <p>Hello World</p>
```

With Drupal I can tweak things so this can work, but how do I do it with CIVI CRM or it is even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I believe its not possible to add php code in CiviCRM text area or ckeditor fields. I guess for security reasons it doesn't allow you to add any code snippets. Alternate solution is to use [hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/list/) to alter the content of the field by using tokens.